# How to set the memory for the Gaussian 09 cubegen utility?

Tags: computational-chemistry, software

I am connected to a supercomputer via SSH and my cluster uses Linux Scientific, I am using the Bash (Unix Shell), I load the modules of Gaussian 09 and Gaussview. I am trying to print orbital densities for a very large tetramer system, but when I try to generate the orbitals on Gaussview, the system crashes because of insufficient memory. On the internet, I found that using the "cubegen" keyword I can generate the cube files of the orbitals. The keyword gives me the power to modify the amount of memory but I do not know how. I go to interactive mode so I can use computational resources directly and on the command shell I do the following:
 (I try changing Gaussian's memory's environmental variable directly at the folder I am at)

```
GAUSS_MEMDEF=16gb
```

then,

```
cubegen 16000000 MO=HOMO xxx.fchk xxx.cub 0 h
```

But it still crashes with the following message,

```
Out-of-memory error in routine DecCub-RdMO (IEnd=      34279201 MxCore=      33546152)
Use %mem=33MW to provide the minimum amount of memory required to complete this step.
Error termination via Lnk1e at Wed Sep 28 16:41:41 2016.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How can I solve this problem? How can I allocate memory to Gaussian from the command window (I do not know where Gaussian folders are located since I just load it as a module, given that the software is already installed on the system)

Comment: First, you need to know which shell is used. You can type `echo $0` to see which shell you are using.

Comment: Anyway, I guess (from the error message), that `GAUSS_MEMDEF=33000000 cubegen bla-bla` should work fine, at least in Bash shell. IIRC, `GAUSS_MEMDEF` is set in words, so since the error message says 33MW are needed, use the value `33000000`, or a bit more, say, `35000000`.

Comment: Note that `cubegen nprocs kind fchkfile cubefile npts format cubefile2`, so the second number should be the number of processes you'd like to use not the memory.

Comment: Btw. `GAUSS_MEMDEF=16gb cubgen [...]` should also work fine. It must be set immediately before the command though. As a over the thumb rule you can use 1MW are about 8MB for a 64 bit machine.

Comment: For cubegen you want to set GAUSS_UDEF: ```
export GAUSS_UDEF=4GB
``` Then you should be able to run cubegen with nprocs=1 (or whatever).

Answer (score 5):

By reading the [information from Gaussian about cubegen](https://web.archive.org/web/20161120225211/http://gaussian.com/g_tech/g_ur/u_cubegen.htm), you would find out, that use of cubegen is like the following:

> **cubegen** *nprocs kind fchkfile cubefile npts format cubefile2*

They further elaborate about nprocs:

> **nprocs**
>
> Number of shared memory processors used for electrostatic potential calculations. A value of 0 is equivalent to 1 (it is the default). Note that this parameter must be included if other parameters are specified. **Previously this parameter was used to specify the amount of memory to allocate. The GAUSS_MEMDEF environment variable should be used instead.**

You can read about setting GAUSS_MEMDEF on the site about the [default.route file](https://web.archive.org/web/20161222222357/http://gaussian.com/g_tech/g_ur/m_defroute.htm).

> **Environment Variables**
>
> All of these directives can also be set via environment variables or UNIX command line arguments. The environment variable *GAUSS_*X*DEF* provides a line equivalent to -*X*- in the Default.Route file. Similarly, the command line argument below specifies the same setting:
>
> $ g09 -x="value"
>
> Similarly, all of the following have the equivalent effect:
>
> *Default.Route* file: **-M- 4GB**
>   **bash** *shell*: **export GAUSS_MDEF=4GB**
>   **tcsh** *shell*: **setenv GAUSS_MDEF 4GB**
>   *command line*: **g09 -m="4GB"** …

Based on that, you could try the way by exporting GAUSS_MDEF to the amount that you want, or by using the commandline. But I have no idea if the latter works with cubegen instead of g09. Let me know. :)

Comment: The latter will not work with cubegen, I tried. Setting (export) the environment variable works very well (it affects the whole session though). It also works immediately specifying it before the command `GAUSS_MEMDEF=X cubegen ...`.